# Showing that these maps are well-defined

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, proof-explanation, quotient-spaces

Let $E$ be a (possibly infinite-dimensional) vector space and $F\subseteq E$ a closed linear subspace. The maps $\Phi : (E^*/F^\bot)\rightarrow F^*$ given by $\Phi(f + F^\bot) = f|_F$ and $\Psi:(E/F)^*\rightarrow F^\bot$ given by $\Psi(f) = f(\cdot + F)$ are well-defined.

I know what "well-defined" means, but I can't follow the proofs.

- For $\Phi$ the proof is: If $f + F^\bot = g + F^\bot$, then there is $h\in F^\bot$ such that $f = g + h$. So $$\Phi(f + F^\bot) = f|_F = (g + h)|_F = g|_F + h|_F = g|_F = \Phi(g + F^\bot)$$
  since $h(x) = 0$ for all $x\in F$. Hence, $\Phi$ is well-defined.
- For $\Psi$ the proof is: $\vert\Psi(f)(x)\vert = \vert f(x + F)\vert \leq \Vert f\Vert \Vert x + F\Vert \leq \Vert f\Vert \Vert x\Vert$, so $\Psi(f)\in E^*$. Now if $x\in F$, then $$\Psi(f)(x) = f(x + F) = f(F) = f(0 + F) = f(0_{E/F}) = 0$$ as $f\in (E/F)^*$. Hence $\Psi$ is well-defined.

I don't see any pattern here. Of course, these are two different functions, but if I was now faced with a third function, I would not know how to start or what to do. I would be very happy if someone could explain me what is going on here so that I know what to do if I was given a third function and had to show it is well-defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think “well-defined” means two different things in the two statements.

1. To say $\Phi$ is well-defined means that, even though the formula uses a representative $f$ of the coset $f + F^\perp$, the answer doesn't change if we choose a different representative.
2. To say $\Psi$ is well-defined means that even though $\Psi(f)$ is defined as an element of $E^*$, it actually belongs to the subspace $F^\perp$.

If you like, the “well-defined-ness” is needed on the domain side of the first and the codomain side of the second.

---

There's a more functorial way to prove these statements. Any time $T \colon W \to W$ is a linear transformation of vector spaces, there is a contravariant dual map $T^* \colon W^* \to V^*$ defined by $T(\lambda)(v) = \lambda(Tv)$. We are given a vector space $E$ and subspace $F$, so there are canonical maps given by the inclusion $\iota \colon F \to E$ and quotient $\psi \colon E \to E/F$. Notice that $\iota^*\colon E^* \to F^*$ is the restriction map $f \mapsto f|_F$, so $F^\perp$ is the kernel of $\iota^*$.

Now notice $\Psi = \psi^*$. Since $\psi \mathrel{\circ} \iota = 0$, we have $\iota^* \mathrel{\circ} \psi^* = 0$. This means that restricting $\psi^*(f)$ to $F$ is the zero map, which is precisely what is needed for $\Psi(f)$ to be in $F^\perp$.

Another quotient map is $\phi \colon E^* \to E^*/F^\perp$. Quotient spaces have the universal property that any map from the full space, whose kernel contains the subspace, factors through the quotient. The map $\Phi$ is the factoring map associated to $\iota^*$, by which we mean $\Phi \mathrel{\circ} \phi = \iota^*$.

Comment: thank you for your answer. In fact, your last sentence reveals the pattern I was asking for. However, it is still not clear to me *why* $\Phi$ needs to be "checked" in the domain side, while $\Psi$ needs to be "checked" on the codomain side.

Comment: Briefly, the reason that each needs to be checked comes right after “even though” in my answers. The authors claim that the domain of $\Phi$ is $E^*/F^\perp$, but it's constructed by action on an element $f \in E^*$. So how do we know the domain isn't actually $E^*$?

Comment: In a similar way, the authors claim that $F^\perp$ is a codomain for $\Psi$, but it's constructed by creating an element of $E^*$. How do we know that the image of $\Psi$ is contained in $F^\perp$?

Comment: I see, so we postulate the domain or codomain of a linear map is a particular space. However, since it is not immediately clear whether this really the case (by the construction of the map), it has to be proven explicitly that the map is well-defined. Thank you very much.

Comment: One quick follow-up question if you don't mind: you added to your answer that the theorem I am talking about can be proven using certain canonical maps. But these maps only define an isomorphism. To show that these isomorphisms are also isometric requires more work (e.g., invoking the Hahn-Banach Theorem), right?

Comment: Hmmm...I get nervous in the infinite dimensional setting, but I am pretty sure that the canonical maps $\iota$, $\psi$, and $\phi$ listed above are bounded. The one thing I know to avoid, and we did avoid it here, is identifying $E^{**}$ with $E$. That's not necessarily true with infinite-dimensional Banach spaces.